# Spacemacs : Setting keybinding for hybrid mode

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, spacemacs

I see this code in ipython layer that set the keybindings to run a cell

  `;; keybindings mirror ipython web interface behavior
      (evil-define-key 'insert ein:notebook-multilang-mode-map
        (kbd "<C-return>") 'ein:worksheet-execute-cell
        (kbd "<S-return>") 'ein:worksheet-execute-cell-and-goto-next)`

I am using hybrid mode and wanted this keybinding there so,
changed this to

`;; keybindings mirror ipython web interface behavior
      (evil-define-key 'hybrid ein:notebook-multilang-mode-map
        (kbd "<C-return>") 'ein:worksheet-execute-cell
        (kbd "<S-return>") 'ein:worksheet-execute-cell-and-goto-next)`

and executed from scratch buffer. But still C-return says -- `<C-return> is undefined`. what could be wrong

Answer (score 0):

The keybinding worked.
When I checked *Messages*, saw an error -- `Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size`, restarted emacs and it started working.
Not sure if the keybinding not taking effect was related to the error.
A restart did the trick.